# How do I fix this javascript. I am new and just started to learn javascript

Tags: javascript

I really have no idea why the code didn't work.

The code was meant to print out the number of clicks done on the button in the console every time you click.

//This is the code

```
let JoinButton = document.getElementById("join-button");

function Click(){
    let count = 0;
    count =+ 1;
    
    if(count = 1){
        console.log (`You have clicked ${count} time`);
    }
    else{
        console.log (`You have clicked ${count} times`);
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i = 10;){
    JoinButton.onclick = Click();
    i += 1;
}

console.log("You have reached the limit of clicking!");
```

Comment: Look, you need to follow a good tutorial methodically. Basically everything in what you posted is wrong.

Comment: If you set `count` to 1 and then never change it again, it cannot get any other value than that. But there are several mistakes here. `=+` is not an operator, but are two operators. `count = 1` is not a comparison, but an assignment, and is always a true expression. Your loop assigns the same thing repeatedly, but always `undefined`, and not the function reference, and always to the same property, ...etc, ...etc. Most of this code is wrong.

Comment: i would suggest running this through step by step in a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achieve something like this, then correcting some lines of code will give you expected result.

```
let JoinButton = document.getElementById("join-button");


let count = 0;
let maxcount = 5;       

JoinButton.addEventListener('click', Click);
function Click(){
    count += 1;
   if(count > maxcount) {
      console.log("You have reached the limit of clicking!");
      return;
   }

    if(count == 1){
        console.log (`You have clicked ${count} time`);
    }
    else{
        console.log (`You have clicked ${count} times`);
    }
}
```